Laravel jQuery AJAX call results in error status 403 SOMETIMES
I'm making a query to a web service using jQuery AJAX. In my local environment, it works well, but in production, env has that error.
The function it does is simply to update an order. The error is thrown only when a user of the system tries to edit an order that another user created.
For example, if Luis tries to edit an order that he made himself, the system saves the changes,
but if Luis tries to edit an order that Lucy made, AJAX responds with a 403 Forbbidden error.
I repeat, this module works correctly in my local env, that is, it lets any user edit any order, but in production it does not.
The route in web.php is POST, it supports, AJAX query.
My PRODUCTION environmentis hosted on an AWS EC2 instance.
In the controller, there is no ID restriction for users, only by roles, but it has nothing to do with it. I am using a super admin role, and I have all the permissions.
AJAX
$( '.btnSaveOrder' ).click(function () {
    $( '#overlay' ).show();
    $( '.btn' ).prop('disabled', true);
    if(orderItems.length == 0){
        erroresValidacion("erroresValidacionPedido", "Debes agregar productos a la orden");
        $( '#overlay' ).hide();
        $( '.btn' ).prop('disabled', false);
        return;
    } else {
        $( '#orderItemList' ).val(JSON.stringify(orderItems));
        $( '#deletedOrderItemList' ).val(JSON.stringify(removedOrderItems));
    }
    $.ajax({
        url    : "{{ route('pedidos.editar') }}",
        method : "POST",
        data   : $( '#formSaveOrder'  ).serialize()
    }).done(function( data ) {
        if(data.resultado === 'OK') {
            //Codigo para reedirigir a nuevo pedido
            confirmarYRedirigir('Orden Guardada','La operación se ha realizado con exito.','listado');
        } else {
            var errorMsg = "<p>Error al editar el pedido.<p><ul>";
            $.each(data.mensajes, function(i,val) { errorMsg += ("<li>" + val + "</li>"); } );
            errorMsg += "</ul>";
            erroresValidacion("erroresValidacionPedido", errorMsg);
        }
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {  //     <- HERE Server Responds with Error 403
        errorDetalle = "";
        console.log("entra");
        // If req debug show errorDetalle
        $.each(jqXHR, function(i,val) { 
            console.log(i);
            console.log(val);
            errorDetalle += "<br>" + i + " : " + val; 

        } );
        erroresValidacion( "erroresValidacionPedido", "Error al editar el pedido." );
    }).always(function() {
        $( '#overlay' ).hide();
        $( '.btn' ).prop('disabled', false);
    });
});

My Form Blade has the csrf token in the form {{ csrf_field() }} and header html with meta tag, the folder where the controller is and the view have all the permissions
try clearing the laravel cache, write the token the AJAX header
The error persists and I don't understand why only in production it doesn't work but in my local env it works without problems
UPDATE:
Check the AWS console, in WAF rules, the rules are the ones that are blocking AJAX requests, I'll have to figure out which one is giving problems

I don't know that having _token as part of the ajax data is the way to go. I would expect to see an ajax header with a X-CSRF-TOKEN reference as mentioned here

sorry, that code I already corrected, that was an attempt, I send the data ->
data : $( '#formSaveOrder' ).serialize()

the 403 response is being sent from your server, you will likely not find such error in your js code. Instead post the relevant server code.
